# React Redux Saga API call

Tags: api, react-native, redux-saga

I am building a food delivery app using **react-native** in which I require to display restaurant list from an API call. I decided to implement it using **Redux-saga** a while back.
After searching through tutorials and different examples on Github I couldn't grasp the concept. Hence my question how do I make sure to dispatch an action while navigating from login screen to home screen which displays the restaurant as desired in Home screen from API response or more specifically store API response in saga index and access it in Home Screen. Sorry for messy code(still a beginner). I apologise in advance for my mistakes in question(my first time asking here).

**src/Sagas/index.js**

```js
import { put, delay, call } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { takeEvery, takeLatest } from "redux-saga";
import axios from "axios";
export function* incrementAsync() {
  yield delay(1000);
  yield put({ type: "INCREMENT" });
}
export function* fetchRestaurantAsync() {
  try {
    console.log("Calling API");
    const response = yield call(
      axios.get,
      "http://18.188.213.236/fooddelivery/api_v2/Homemaster/getCategories/0/1/25.204849/55.27078"
    );
    console.log("reponse", response);
    yield put({ type: "FETCH_SUCCEEDED" }, restaurant);
    const restaurant = response ? response.data.category : [];

    // const data = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.url);
    // yield put({ type: "FETCH_SUCCEEDED", data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("requestfailed: could not ");
    console.log("error", error);
    // yield put({ type: "FETCH_FAILED", error });
  }
}
export function* watchfetchRestaurant() {
  yield takeEvery("FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchRestaurantAsync);
}
export function* watchCart() {
  yield takeEvery("INCREMENT_ASYNC", incrementAsync);
}
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield { watchCart };
  yield { watchfetchRestaurant };
}
```

**src/components/Home.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, ScrollView, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Container, Card, CardItem, Body, Left, Right } from "native-base";
import RestaurantDetail from "./RestaurantDetail";
import axios from "axios";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      banner: [],
      nearByRestaurant: []
    };
    axios
      .get(
        "http://18.188.213.236/fooddelivery/api_v2/Bannermaster/getBannerList/{latitude}/{longitude}"
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ banner: response.data.result });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(
          "There has been a problem with your fetch operation: " + error
        );
        throw error;
      });
    axios
      .get(
        "http://18.188.213.236/fooddelivery/api_v2/Restaurantmaster/get_restaurants/0/25.204849/55.27078"
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({ nearByRestaurant: response.data.result });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(
          "There has been a problem with your fetch operation: " + error
        );
        throw error;
      });
  }

  renderRestaurants() {
    return this.props.restaurant.map(restaurants => {
      return restaurants.dishes.map(dishes => (
        <RestaurantDetail key={dishes.dish_id} dishes={dishes} />
      ));
    });
  }
  renderBanner() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: "row" }}
        horizontal={true}
      >
        {this.state.banner.map(result => {
          return (
            <View
              key={result.id}
              style={{
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center"
              }}
            >
              <Image
                resizeMode="cover"
                source={{
                  uri: result.image
                }}
                style={{ position: "relative", height: 300, width: 400 }}
              />
              <Text style={styles.bannertextStyle}>{result.messages}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
  rendernearByRestaurant() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: "row" }}
          horizontal={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
          {this.state.nearByRestaurant.map(result => {
            return (
              <Card
                key={result.restaurant_id}
                style={{
                  height: 200,
                  width: 230,
                  backgroundColor: "transparent"
                }}
              >
                <Body>
                  <Image
                    resizeMode="cover"
                    source={{
                      uri: result.image
                    }}
                    style={{
                      height: 150,
                      width: 220,
                      borderRadius: 5
                    }}
                  />
                </Body>

                <CardItem
                  footer
                  style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                >
                  <Left>
                    <Text numberOfLines={1}>{result.restaurant_name}</Text>
                  </Left>

                  <Right>
                    <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                      {result.start_price +
                        "-" +
                        result.end_price +
                        " " +
                        "USD"}
                    </Text>
                  </Right>
                </CardItem>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View styles={styles.containerStyle}>
          <ScrollView>
            <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
              <View styles={styles.bannerStyle}>{this.renderBanner()}</View>
            </ScrollView>
            <View>
              <LinearGradient
                style={{
                  height: 100,
                  borderColor: "transparent"
                }}
                locations={[0.4, 0.8]}
                colors={["#FF8500", "#FB3D2D"]}
                start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
              >
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    alignContent: "flex-end",
                    justifyContent: "space-between"
                  }}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontFamily: "Poppins",
                      fontWeight: "600",
                      color: "white",
                      fontSize: 20
                    }}
                  >
                    Rigel Picks
                  </Text>
                  <Image source={require("../assets/ios/filter.png")} />
                </View>
              </LinearGradient>
            </View>
            <View>
              <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
              //Saga Api response as 'restaurant' here
                <RestaurantDetail
                  restaurants={this.props.restaurant.slice(0, 1)}
                  navigations={this.props.navigation}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10 }}>
                <LinearGradient
                  style={{
                    borderColor: "transparent",
                    borderRadius: 8,
                    flex: 1
                  }}
                  locations={[0.4, 0.8]}
                  colors={["#FF8500", "#FB3D2D"]}
                  start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                  end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
                >
                  <CardItem header style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>
                    <Left>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          textAlign: "left",
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: "white",
                          fontWeight: "bold"
                        }}
                      >
                        Near By Restaurants
                      </Text>
                    </Left>
                    <Right>
                      <Text style={styles.linkStyle}>See all</Text>
                    </Right>
                  </CardItem>
                  <CardItem style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>
                    <View>{this.rendernearByRestaurant()}</View>
                  </CardItem>
                </LinearGradient>
              </View>
              <View style={{ borderRadius: 8, padding: 10 }}>               
                //Saga Api response as 'restaurant' here

                <RestaurantDetail
                  restaurants={this.props.restaurant.slice(1)}
                  navigations={this.props.navigation}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerStyle: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: "transparent" },
  bannerStyle: {
    flex: 2,
    alignContent: "center",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  bannertextStyle: {
    fontFamily: "Poppins",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 40,
    fontSize: 30,
    color: "white",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },

  gradientStyle: {
    height: 30,
    fontSize: 5,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  categoryRestaurantStyle: {
    borderRadius: 3,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignContent: "center"
  },
  imageStyle: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100
  },
  restaurantNameStyle: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  dishnameStyle: {
    fontSize: 5,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  fontcolorStyle: {
    color: "white"
  },
  linkStyle: {
    fontFamily: "Poppins",
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "white",
    textDecorationLine: "underline"
  }
});
function mapStateToPros(state) {
  return {
    restaurant: state.restaurant
  };
}
const HomeComponent = connect(
  mapStateToPros,
  null
)(Home);
export { HomeComponent as Home };
```

**src/components/Reducers/index.js**

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import counterReducer from "./counterReducer";
import fetchReducer from "./fetchReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  ctr: counterReducer,
  fetch: fetchReducer
});
```

**src/components/Reducers/fetchReducer.js**

```js
export default (state = { restaurant: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_REQUESTED":
    case "FETCH_SUCCEEDED":
      return {
        ...state,
        restaurant: action.payload
      };
    case "FETCH_FAILED":
      return {
        ...state,

        restaurant: []
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: The `constructor` is not the right place to call an api.  Usually, that would happen in `componentDidMount`.  But since you are using sagas, I think the pattern would involve dispatching an action in whatever component lifecycle method you see fit, then letting the saga do its side effect work.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Thank you for the answer. But currently problem is Saga is not at all called when action is created or dispatched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. It was in **Saga/index.js**. I was not calling sagas properly in `rootSaga()`. I changed it to `yield all([call (saga1),call(saga2)...,call(saga11)])`.